# bootstrap classes not showing in django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-cms

i'm trying out BootStrap in Djangocms 3.0, and can't get it to work.  i created a simple html (code below), which is a composite of a banner from [this tutorial](http://www.pythondiary.com/blog/Sep.18,2012/bootstrap-and-django-14-guide.html), and a simple modal from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).  i'm call it through a django view.

when i go to the page, what i see depends on what browser i use. in chrome, i see a black banner and the Bootstrap link, and nothing else (not Home, About, etc.., nor the modal). in IE and Mozilla i see the whole banner, but no modal.

if i comment out the references to the bootstrap css and js files, then everything (all the links and the modal contents) appear, but without any styling, of course.  so it seems that i have the {{ STATIC_URL }} correct.  it is recognizing the classes, just not displaying them correctly (or at all)?

any ideas? thanks!!

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="brand" href="/">Bootstrap</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

</body>
```

**UPDATE:**
i reinstalled djangocms, rebuilt my entire site, and re-populated my DB, and now things display properly in the above example.  i can even get a modal dialog to pop up and sort of function.  however, it works funny.  for example, sometimes, the close button works, and sometimes it doesnt.  most of the time, everything on the page after the modal element is unresponsive, though not always.  i know this is very vague, but the problems are all over the place, so its hard to describe accurately in less than a book.  i feel its a conflict of some sort with django, but besides the imported bootstrap files, i have only two js functions of my own, and very little css at this point.

has anyone had similar problems implementing bootstrap in Djano.

Comment: Use Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the elements. `{{STATIC_URL}}`? This tutorial might interest you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

try to save all you static file under :
app_name/static/app_name/

in your html code add:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'app_name/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and check for [static file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/)more information